# which method of fragment is used to load image from fire base?

Tags: android, android-fragments, firebase-realtime-database, android-activity, android-glide

```
databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange( DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                Glide.with(get Context()).load(dataSnapshot.get Value(String.class)).into(profImage);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError){

            }
        });
```

Comment: in which method I should place above code?

Answer (score 0):

Override the **onActivityCreated** method of fragment and place it in that method

```
    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

          databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange( DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                Glide.with(get Context()).load(dataSnapshot.get Value(String.class)).into(profImage);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError){

            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: You cannot start a load on a not yet attached View or a Fragment where getActivity() returns null (which usually occurs when getActivity() is called before the Fragment is attached or after the Fragment is destroyed).

Comment: try overriding onViewCreated Method of fragment

Comment: same happened with onViewCreated